# any advantage or disadvantage to have mysql 5.6 on a linux server over on a window server

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

i am planning to decide to use mysql5.6 on a window server 2012 or a linux server. Can someone gives me some general advises between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching to Disk should be your biggest concern.

Windows is notorious for caching writes to the operating through the operating system. What this means is that any transaction you write in logs, in `.ibd` tablespace files, in the system tablespace (ibdata1), would be at the mercy of Windows to get writes to disk.

One particular option I am thinking of is `innodb_flush_method`.

Since the [MySQL Documentation on `innodb_flush_method`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) says

> On Windows systems, the flush method is always async_unbuffered and cannot be changed.

the option is not supported in Windows.

You can set [innodb_flush_method] to `O_DIRECT` to personally make InnoDB handle its own disk caching. Even with Linux, be careful. VMs and bare metal machines with new ext4 kernals actually fake O_DIRECT. See [mysqlperformanceblog post on this](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/)

Definitely, you should NOT USE WINDOWS !!!

Comment: The innodb_flush_method documentation doesn't explain, but I'd guess async_unbuffered means InnoDB on Windows is opening the files with the flags  FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING (for unbuffered) and FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED (for async I/O). That is how Windows-oriented RDBMSs do I/O and *should* avoid any double-buffering of the I/Os in Windows. Personally I'd avoid MySQL on Windows because it's developed, tested, and run largely on UNIX & Linux and MySQL experts are in the UNIX/Linux space. So I agree that you should definitely NOT USE WINDOWS for MySQL, though I'm not sure if your reasons are correct.